# MongoDB: Property 'initializeUnorderedBulkOp' of object is not function

Tags: mongodb, insert, bulk

I'm in version 2.4.8. My objective is to execute BulkInsert:

mongos> use MyDB
switched to db MyDB

mongos> var bulk = db.test.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
Wed Apr 23 14:01:40.284 TypeError: Property 'initializeUnorderedBulkOp' of object MyDB.test is not a function

Comment: Again, my error message that I am trying to resolve is this:"Property 'initializeUnorderedBulkOp' of object MyDB.test is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

The method you're calling is new to 2.6.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk

Comment: Ben, thank you so much for your help. What is available in 2.4.8 for BULK INSERT? (I cannot upgrade to 2.6 due to bureaucratic restrictions)

Comment: @vrdba:In MongoDB 2.4 there is also a bulk insert feature - you can pass an array of documents to `insert()`: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/bulk-inserts/. The bulk API in MongoDB 2.4 is more limited in that it only returns a single error for the batch and is only available for inserts. The [MongoDB 2.6 bulk API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) includes additional write operations and more detailed error/result reporting.

Comment: Thank you, Stennie (@Stennie). It works for me now in v.2.4.8 however it works only on small number of record in the JSON file. My real JSON file has 2.5 million documents in it. So, when I ussue command like this: mongos> load("bulk1.js"), it just hands forever. I thought that BULK INSERT would be faster than "mongoimport" but it does not look like that at this time or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I have a typo in the above comment: the session is hanging forever. In general, i am wondering if BULK INSERT would be faster than "mongoimport". I need to load 150 separate JSON files with 2.5 document in each file. And i only have 4 hours time window to get the job done. Thank you, vrdba

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade mongo AND mongoose.

Older versions on mongoose do not expose all of the methods of the underlying mongo collection.  I was banging my head on this for a while.

solution:
npm install mongoose